# Do I need updated documents to show at border control due to delayed trip?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, borders

My trip to UK was planned from Sep6-Sep30, 2021. I expected my tourist visa to come before that but visa got delayed by 2 weeks. I submitted **Employment Leave Letter** and **Invitation Letter** in support of my visa application.

My visa has been issued which is valid from Sep 15 onwards. The delay was caused by UKVI

My updated trip is now from Sep 29-Oct18 2021. I am now confused if I should get a new Employment Leave letter from my employer and new Invitation letter as I have read that immigration officers checks all the documents to determine if you would leave the country after the trip.

Has anyone been in this situation before? How did you justify the old documents at Border control if asked.

Comment: What does "visa got delayed by 2 weeks" mean? Who or what caused this delay? Have you received a UK visa reflecting the original dates of Sept 6 - Sept 30? If so, what are the visa dates? When do you plan to travel?

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear as to whether you actually now have a UK visa or not.

If you do not have a valid UK visa when it comes time to fly to the UK (or take the first or an interim flight on your itinerary towards the UK), the airline will not allow you to board. The airline won't care about the leave letter or invitation letter, but will notice and act on whether you possess (and will arrive in the UK with) a valid UK visa allowing your entry into the UK at that time.

Remember too that you must comply with whatever covid and health-related requirements (including quarantine) imposed on travelers arriving in the UK. These requirements change frequently, and vary between the individual countries within the UK (i.e., England, Scotland, Wales).

When you land in the UK, the UK Immigration officer will see the difference in dates between what you specified in your application (Sept 6 to Sept 30) and what might then be two weeks later (perhaps Sept 20 - Oct 15). The officer will certainly want to know if your employer and the person inviting you agree with the new dates, and may ask why the dates changed. Be prepared to answer the question; there's nothing wrong with a date change - plans do change in the real world - but even if you then have an updated visa, the officer may want to know what caused the change in dates.

Most importantly, prepare yourself for your landing interview by obtaining new letters from both your employer and the person inviting you, which letters reflect the actual dates of your travel. Have these letters printed out, and carry them with you.

Comment: Thanks, I will obtain the updated letters. The delay was caused by UKVI due to high number of visa application

Answer (score 3):

I cleared my immigration at LHR yesterday and luckily they did not ask me any questions regarding the change in travel dates. I did kept all the updated documents as mentioned by [DavidSupportsMonica](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/76708/davidsupportsmonica).

I was asked the following questions by the immigration officers.

> 1. What is the purpose of your visit
> 2. How long have you known your gf
> 3. How long are you planning to stay
> 4. What does she do in UK?

Comment: Thanks for following-up. Even though you weren't asked about the date change, it was very good to be prepared just in case.